# Making a directive mandatory for every query/mutation

Tags: go, graphql, authorization, directive

I am using [github.com/99designs/gqlgen](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen) to create my GraphQL in Go. I have a directive in there called hasRole for authorization purposes. The thing is that I want to make this directive apply to every field in Query/Mutation, in case a developer forgets adding it when creating new Query/Mutation. E.g.:

`createUser(name: String): String @hasRole(role: [Admin])` - this is ok

`createUser(name: String): String` - not ok

Any way to prevent the query/mutation from happening is acceptable. Is there any way to make this possible? Doesn't matter if it is done during generation, starting of the program, etc.